# Use oracle crate in Rust

Tags: database, oracle, rust

I am trying to connect to an oracle db with rust.
I installed this library:

```
[dependencies]
oracle = "0.3.2"
```

and this is the code:

```
extern crate oracle;

use oracle::{Connection, Error};

fn main() {
    let conn = Connection::connect("user", "pwd", "//194.1.1.253/db");
    if conn.is_ok() {
        // let sql = "SELECT * FROM mat_anag WHERE ditmat = :1 AND fvl = :2";
        let sql = "SELECT * FROM mat_anag WHERE ditmat = 'XXL' AND fvl = ' '";
        let rows = conn.query(sql, &[])?;
    } else {
        println!("KO");
    }
}
```

the problem is that I get this error: error[E0599]: no method named `query` found for enum `std::result::Result<oracle::Connection, oracle::Error>` in the current scope

---

EDIT

thank you all for the advice.
I modified the code and it works:

```
extern crate oracle;

use oracle::{Connection};

fn main() {
            let conn = Connection::connect("user", "pwd", "//194.1.1.253/db"); {
        Ok(conn) => {
            let sql = "SELECT * FROM anag_conti WHERE ditagenda = 'XXL' AND fvl = ' '";
            let rows = conn.query(sql, &[]).unwrap();
            for r in rows {
                let row = r.unwrap();
                let conto: String = row.get("CONTO").unwrap();
                println!("{}", conto);
            }
        }
        Err(_e) => panic!("Errore di connessione")
    };
}
```

Comment: You have a Result because `Connection::connect` can fail. _"Failure is represented with the `Result` type. A `Result` may be either an `Ok`, which is the success case, or an `Err`, the failure case."_ Checking for `is_ok` does not automatically convert the value into its `Ok` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `conn` variable is a `Result` type which wraps the `Connection` type you need, because it has a possible error.

So what you want is access to the connection which you can do in several ways:

- Easy but bad way: `conn.unwrap().query()`.
  This will panic on an error. You have the same problem with `expect("Error message")`.
- It is better to handle your error:

```
match conn {
 Ok(conn) => conn.query(),
 Err(_) => println!("KO")
}
```

- Since you just print `"KO"`, you don't use the error, so you can do something like this too:

```
if let Ok(conn) = conn {
   conn.query();
} else {
   println!("KO");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `Connection::connect` returns a `Result`, because the connection could have failed. You need to handle this in your program.

The easiest way is to call `.unwrap()` or `.expect()` on the result. These methods return the `Ok` value of the result, and `panic!` if there is an error.

```
extern crate oracle;

use oracle::{Connection, Error};

fn main() {
    let conn = Connection::connect("md_s", "md_s", "//194.1.1.253/c4b").expect("Could not connect");
    // let sql = "SELECT * FROM mat_anag WHERE ditmat = :1 AND fvl = :2";
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM mat_anag WHERE ditmat = 'XXL' AND fvl = ' '";
    let rows = conn.query(sql, &[])?;
}
```

You can also use a `match` expression for more powerful error handling.

```
let conn = match Connection::connect("md_s", "md_s", "//194.1.1.253/c4b") {
    Ok(conn) => conn,
    Err(e) => panic!("Encountered an error when connecting to the database: {:?}", e)
};
```

Or something like:

```
match Connection::connect("md_s", "md_s", "//194.1.1.253/c4b") {
    Ok(conn) => {
      <do something with the result here>
    },
    Err(e) => panic!("Encountered an error when connecting to the database: {:?}", e)
};
```

You might find [the documentation page for `Result` useful](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) and also [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html).